# MySQL Select is not selecting based on given criteria

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run a SQL query but its not showing me the exact data.
In my search option, I have 4 options: search by start and end date, by website, by landing page, and by brand.

When I search by date and website, the query run fine, but when I search by landing page and brand, it's showing all values. I want the user to give an option to either search by website, landing page, or brand, or the user can search by all fields, but the date needs to be selected.

Here is my query I am running:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT brand, cpa, sum(ftds), website, landingpage, ftddate
    FROM ftd
    WHERE ftddate BETWEEN CAST('$startdate' AS DATE)
    AND CAST('$enddate' AS DATE)
    AND (website='$website')
    OR (landingpage='$landingpage') 
    group by brand
";
```

Comment: $sql ="SELECT brand, cpa, sum(ftds),website,landingpage,ftddate 
  FROM ftd 
  WHERE ftddate 
  BETWEEN CAST('$startdate' AS DATE) AND CAST('$enddate' AS DATE) AND ((website='$website') OR (landingpage='$landingpage') OR (brand='$brand')) group by brand";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$sql ="SELECT `brand`, `cpa`, sum(`ftds`),`website`,`landingpage`,`ftddate` FROM ftd WHERE `ftddate` BETWEEN CAST('$startdate' AS DATE) AND CAST('$enddate' AS DATE) AND ((`website`='$website') OR (`landingpage`='$landingpage') OR (`brand`='$brand')) group by `brand`";
```

**UPDATED:**

```
        $concatenate='';

        $group_by_string ='  group by `brand`';
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        if(!empty($website))
        {
           $concatenate.=" AND `website`='$website'  ";

        }
        if(!empty($landingpage))
        {
           $concatenate.=" AND `landingpage`='$landingpage'  ";
        }
        if(!empty($brand))
        {
            $concatenate.=" AND `brand`='$brand'  ";
            $group_by_string ='  group by `landingpage`';
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                

        }

        $sql ="SELECT `brand`, `cpa`, sum(`ftds`),`website`,`landingpage`,`ftddate` 
        FROM ftd 
        WHERE `ftddate` 
        BETWEEN CAST('$startdate' AS DATE) 
        AND CAST('$enddate' AS DATE) 
        $concatenate  $group_by_string ";
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**UPDATE 2**
     below condition overwrite the $sql query string when brand not empty and all are empty . this one meet your expectation

```
        if(!empty($brand) && empty($website) && empty($landingpage))
       {
       $sql ="SELECT `brand`, `cpa`, `ftds`,`website`,`landingpage`,`ftddate` 
        FROM ftd 
        WHERE `ftddate` 
        BETWEEN CAST('$startdate' AS DATE) 
        AND CAST('$enddate' AS DATE) 
        $concatenate  $group_by_string";

        }
```

Comment: I have tried your query but showing other landingpages as well :(   SELECT brand, cpa, sum(ftds),website,landingpage,ftddate FROM ftd WHERE ftddate BETWEEN CAST('2016-07-15' AS DATE) AND CAST('2016-07-30' AS DATE) AND ((website='http://www.top10sites.co.uk') OR (landingpage='/FishSites')) group by brand

Comment: `Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ftd\custom-report.php on line 153

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ftd\custom-report.php on line 158`

Comment: echo $sql and copy the query and run the query directly into database and check

Comment: or may be your query returning empty result set @Atif

Comment: i have checked the query into database its running, why its not running on website :(? i am using php with while loop

Comment: may be you did mistake here mysqli_query($connection_string,$query_string); @Atif

Comment: `<?php $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$count = 1;
$total = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?><tr>
<td><?php echo $count; $count++; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["brand"] ?></td>
<td>&pound;<?php echo $row["cpa"] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["sum(ftds)"] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["website"] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["landingpage"] ?></td>
<td><?php 
$cpa = $row["cpa"];
$ftd = $row["sum(ftds)"];
$earnings = $cpa * $ftd;
echo "&pound;"; echo $earnings;
?></td><?php
$earnings = $cpa * $ftd;
$total += $earnings;
}?>`

Comment: i dont know where i miss something :(

Comment: when i select only website its showing nothing `SELECT `brand`, `cpa`, sum(ftds),`website`,`landingpage`,`ftddate` FROM ftd WHERE `ftddate` BETWEEN CAST('2016-07-15' AS DATE) AND CAST('2016-07-30' AS DATE) AND website='http://www.10newssites.co.uk' AND landingpage='' group by `brand``

Comment: may problem is your connection string name and query string variable name same so that is problem here .you change your query string variable $conn into $concatenate like this  @Atif

Comment: Thanks Jothi... Its working fine :) Just have a last quick question. Search by brand i dont want sum(ftds) and group by brand. Is that possible to do that? OR is their anyway i can do in a while loop i php?

Comment: if answers is useful make it with green its useful to future users @Atif

Comment: Thanks, would be great if you can change only group by landingpage instead of group by brand Only when user select brand. I have run this query on database and its looks right result just changed "group by landingpage". Here is the query below               `SELECT brand,cpa,sum(ftds),website,landingpage,ftddate FROM ftd WHERE ftddate BETWEEN CAST('2016-07-25' AS DATE) AND CAST('2016-07-30' AS DATE) AND website='http://www.topsites.co.uk' AND brand='24options' group by landingpage`

Comment: when where condition have brand while you need to group by with landingpage  is it ?

Comment: yeah i update my answer by your need   note that new variable $group_by_string see my updated answer @Atif

Comment: by your need you don't need update 2 don't consider this @Atif